# Find expected value of $x_t$

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Given that a series {$x_t$} where $x_t=sin(t+U)$, $U$ has uniform distrubution on $(0,2\pi)$.

Now $E(U)=\pi$, $var(U)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}$, I noticed that $sin(x)$ is a periodic function, $U$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$, so is there some useful information?

Here I think it is hard to find the p.d.f of this $sin(\cdot)$ function or using Taylor's expansion. Can anyone help me with that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by “series” here? What are the values of $t?$

Comment: We can consider it as a process, $t$ = $1,2, \cdots$